# Solution to enum type with too many fields? [Improvement]

Tags: java, enums

As the project gradually expanded, the exited enum type need to expand fields. For example, there is one enum class named ECityArea, which used to store city related informs, at the beginning only the city name is necessary, then we need state informs, alias, image location and db alias etc. So the enum fields come a little large, like the following codes :

```
ECityArea(String name, 
          String state, 
          String alias, 
          String imageLocation, 
          String imageFolder, 
          String imageAlias, 
          String dbAlias)
```

All developers can obviously find that there are too many fields, later there may be more fields. Predictably, the ECityArea itself will be too large and difficult to read, then there should be some solutions to this dilemma.

Just now, I got one idea and share it to you.

Itegrate some of the fields together as another enum class. like the following:

```
ECityAreaImageRelated(String imageLocation, String imageFolder, String imageAlias)

ECityArea(String name, String state, ECityAreaImageRelated imageRelated, String dbAlias)
```

Any other solutions provided? Thanks.

Comment: Well this is not just specific to enums but to any classes in general. Like for example if you have a class called Person, then it is ok to have fields like his name, age, gender and so on in this class. But it is not ok to have fields like address line 1, address line 2, city, country and so on. It is better to group the fields into another class called Address.....the same idea applies here as well

Comment: @user3493289 I agree part of your points, for general classes, we always group some of the related fields into another one called helper or sometimes we use builder pattern to this situation. But to enum type, I suppose we could think deeper of the enum structure itself and do some research to make it diff with the traditional solutions. It is the original intention of the question. Thanks for your view.

Comment: @Ivan, Wouldn't you want to want to split db related information into another Enum then? It doesn't seem to fit the domain model of City. Otherwise, yes, this is what you want according to the "Single Responsibility Principle".

Comment: @ChrisWohlert Yes, to split db related informs is also added to todo list, till now, helper class is the only choice to make codes better.